# User package subcaption is centering all my figure captions

Tags: floats, subcaption

I've been writing an article which includes a great deal of figures. In order to show more of them I imported the packages caption and subcaption. With these I managed to plot figures and subfigures, but importing these packages seems to have centered all the figure texts, including those with multiple lines. Is there a way to bring the caption text back to its uncentered style without removing the subcaption package?

Comment: Welcome on tex.stackexchange.This can be configured as an option of the packages. Please look at the manuals (e.g. run `texdoc caption` or `texdoc subcaption` in a teminal).

Comment: I'm using overleaf, so how would i go forward to alter those options?

Comment: Check online on ctan.org: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption